# Printing Raw Data in Terminal Server

Tags: c++, printing, terminal-services

Here is the scenario:

- I have a Windows Server 2008 with Terminal Server (No Domain Controller, No join to Domain)
- I have a client machine with Windows XP SP3 updated (.NET 3.0 SP1 and .NET 4.0)
- I'm Using Embarcadero C++Builder (BCB6)
- I have a ticket printer (Thermal Printer, POS Printer, Epson, Zebra, etc.)

When I connect to the terminal server, the printer works OK. I tested printing a test page.

When I use my software to send the raw data in the terminal server on the local computer, I get this error:

```
Windows Presentation Foundation terminal server print W has encountered a
problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.
```

I followed the advice from this [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2021394) with no luck.

I used to print directly to LPT1:, but with Windows Server 2008 it's getting harder to make this work, so we have to change the way we print to this kind of printer.

Here is the code that I'm using. I tested locally and it works fine, but in the terminal server doesn't work:

```
bool TForm1::RawDataToPrinter(char* szPrinterName, char* lpData, unsigned int dwCount )
{
    int BytesWritten;
    HANDLE hPrinter;
    TDocInfo1 DocInfo;
    bool bStatus = false;
    int dwJob = 0;
    unsigned long dwBytesWritten = 0;

    // Open a handle to the printer.
    bStatus = OpenPrinter( szPrinterName, &hPrinter, NULL );

    if( bStatus )
    {
        // Fill in the structure with info about this "document."
        DocInfo.pDocName = "My Document";
        DocInfo.pOutputFile = NULL;
        DocInfo.pDatatype = "RAW";

        // to indicate that the application will be sending document data to the printer.
        dwJob = StartDocPrinter( hPrinter, 1, (LPBYTE)&DocInfo );

        if ( dwJob > 0 )
        {
            // Start a page.
            bStatus = StartPagePrinter( hPrinter );
            bStatus = true;

            if( bStatus )
            {
                // Send the data to the printer.
                bStatus = WritePrinter( hPrinter, lpData, dwCount, &dwBytesWritten );
                EndPagePrinter ( hPrinter );
            }

            // Inform the spooler that the document is ending.
            EndDocPrinter( hPrinter );
        }
        // Close the printer handle.
        ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
    }
    // Check to see if correct number of bytes were written.
    if (!bStatus || (dwBytesWritten != dwCount))
        bStatus = false;
    else
        bStatus = true;

    return bStatus;
}
```

I copied this code from a example in Microsoft's Support. I also tried changing the "RAW" to "TEXT" but I get the same error.

I tried this code, because it uses the GDI to print:

```
long pageline;

char prueba[255];

Printer()->SetPrinter(ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex].c_str(), "WINSPOOL", "", NULL);
Printer()->BeginDoc();

pageline = 0;
while(pageline < Memo1->Lines->Count)
{
    Printer()->Canvas->TextOut(10, (10 + Printer()->Canvas->TextHeight("Hi! There")) * pageline, Memo1->Lines->Strings[pageline]);
    pageline++;
}

Printer()->EndDoc();
```

This is a example that I found in the Embarcadero Forum.

I also verified TsWpfWrp.exe. I tried replacing it by the one in the server, but it does nothing, doesn't send the error, but also won't send any data.

There is another way to do this? Do I have something wrong in the code?

I appreciated any help or insight.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, is the Easy Print driver, it expect in RAW Mode the XPS specification, but I was sending only text.

I disabled the Easy Print to put the printer in Fallback mode( something like that), this is where the Terminal Server, first it look for the installed driver then for the Easy Print (this can be verified in the properties of the printer in advanced options).

Now it works, thanks.